# Contour integral of entire function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function. I want to show that for all $N \geq 2$, and all $r> 0$, one has $$\int_{\left| z \right| = r} \frac{1}{z^N} \overline{f(z)} dz=0.$$

Since $f$ is entire, we know that $\int_{\left| z \right| = r} f(z) dz= 0$ for all $r >0$.

We may also expand $f$ into  a power series. This gives us \begin{eqnarray*}
f(z) &=& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n \\
\therefore \overline{f(z)} &=& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \overline{a_n} \cdot  \overline{z}^n \\
\therefore \frac{1}{z^N} \overline{f(z)} &=& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \overline{a_n} \cdot \overline{z}^{n} \frac{1}{z^N} \\
&=& \sum_{n=0}^{N} \overline{a_n} \frac{\left| z\right|^{2n}}{z^{2n}} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \overline{a_{n+N+1}} \cdot \overline{z}^n
\end{eqnarray*}

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

By conjugation it suffices to show

$$\int_{\lvert z\rvert = r} \frac{1}{\overline{z}^N} f(z)\, d\overline{z} = 0$$

On the circle $\lvert z\rvert = r$, $z\bar{z} = r^2$, thus $\bar{z}^N = r^{2N}z^{-N}$ and $d\overline{z} = -\dfrac{\overline{z}}{z}\, dz = -\dfrac{r^2}{z^2}\, dz$. Hence the integral equals

$$\int_{\lvert z\rvert = r} \frac{z^N}{r^{2N}} f(z) \left(-\frac{r}{z^2}\, dz\right) = -\frac{1}{r^{2N-2}}\int_{\lvert z\rvert = r} z^{N-2}f(z)\, dz$$

The latter integral equals zero by Cauchy's theorem since $z^{N-2}f(z)$ is entire for all $N \ge 2$.